# Bottom scroll appears as browser re-sized to mobile resolution

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css, media-queries

Here is the link to my page: http://smuggler-cow-23486.netlify.com/dashboard

When I click on Toggle menu button at the Top right corner at mobile size window, it shows bottom scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `overflow: hidden;` to remove the scroll for horizontal

```
.dashboard {
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I want to make it responsive not just hiding the bar.

Comment: you want de scroll bar to be responsive? please state clear what you want to achieve

Comment: When I re-size browser to mobile resolution width that is 240px. The bottom scroll appears under my content. Makes sense? I want remove that.

Comment: i canged my answere so it would work. it should remove the horizontal scroll for mobile

Comment: Once again on real mobile device it shows the bottom scroll.

Comment: i will be looking in to your issue, i found a other problem. you can zoom in and out. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />` this should fix that